# How align center in FlowLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

how to set the center alignment of FlowLayout

i tried:

```
myLayout = new FlowLayout;
myLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
```

but it did not help

I want the child widgets to be in the center and not snuggle to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into implementation of FlowLayout::doLayout() you will find that nothing dealing with layout's alignment, that is why your approach not works at all. 
You may directly edit FlowLayout::doLayout() and adding if-else case for FlowLayout::alignment() to make it fit your requirement. Notice that you must also change geometry of previously added item when adding new item, so it will be quite more complicated than the default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In PyQT I have modified the [FlowLayout Example](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/examples/example_widgets_layouts_flowlayout.html) to align items horizontally and vertically for each row.

```
def _do_layout(self, rect, test_only):
    line_height = 0

    # Center the item group horizontally and vertically
    # taking into account the width and height of the items in the row
    row_widths = [0]
    row_heights = [0]
    row = 0
    for item in self._item_list:
        wid = item.widget()
        space_x = self.spacing() + wid.style().layoutSpacing(
            QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Horizontal
        )
        item_width = item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
        if row_widths[row] + item_width < rect.right():
            row_widths[row] += item_width
        else:
            row += 1
            row_widths.append(item_width)
            row_heights.append(item.sizeHint().height())

        row_heights[row] = max(row_heights[row], item.sizeHint().height())

    spacing = self.spacing()

    x = int((rect.width() - row_widths[0]) / 2)
    y = int((rect.height() - sum(row_heights)) / 2)

    row = 0
    for item in self._item_list:
        style = item.widget().style()
        layout_spacing_x = style.layoutSpacing(
            QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Horizontal
        )
        layout_spacing_y = style.layoutSpacing(
            QSizePolicy.PushButton, QSizePolicy.PushButton, Qt.Vertical
        )
        space_x = spacing + layout_spacing_x
        space_y = spacing + layout_spacing_y
        next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
        if next_x - space_x > rect.right() and line_height > 0:
            row += 1
            x = int((rect.width() - row_widths[row]) / 2)
            y = y + line_height + space_y
            next_x = x + item.sizeHint().width() + space_x
            line_height = 0

        if not test_only:
            item.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(x, y), item.sizeHint()))

        x = next_x
        line_height = max(line_height, item.sizeHint().height())

    return y + line_height - rect.y()
```